# sql query slow 3 leftjoins with where clausel

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, left-join

This first query have one and clausle more and slow down from 200ms to 9-13seconds
i dont get why its so.

If i remove all where clause i get ~200ms just if i add one more and it will be slow.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* , p.*, p2.*, p3.*
FROM article a 
LEFT JOIN pro p ON a.id = p.article_id 
LEFT JOIN pro p2 ON a.id = p2.article_id
LEFT JOIN pro p3 ON a.id = p3.article_id
WHERE a.is_active = true 
AND p.name = 'hotel_stars' 
AND p2.name = 'article_journey_days' 
AND p3.name = 'article_persons' 
AND p3.int_value > 0 AND p3.int_value < 7 
AND p.int_value > 0 AND p.int_value < 5
```

Result

```
319 Datensätze

Laufzeit gesamt: 9,602.081 ms

SELECT DISTINCT a.* , p.*, p2.*, p3.*
FROM article a 
LEFT JOIN property p ON a.id = p.article_id 
LEFT JOIN property p2 ON a.id = p2.article_id
LEFT JOIN property p3 ON a.id = p3.article_id
WHERE a.is_active = true 
AND p.name = 'hotel_stars' 
AND p2.name = 'article_property_journey_days' 
AND p3.name = 'article_property_persons' 
AND p3.int_value > 0 AND p3.int_value < 7 
// AND p.int_value > 0 AND p.int_value < 5 (removed)
```

Result

```
469 Datensätze

Laufzeit gesamt: 278.453 ms
```

Where is the Problem?
Thx

EDIT EXPLAIN PLAN:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=24113.80..24113.81 rows=1 width=3528)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..24113.69 rows=1 width=3528)
        Join Filter: (a.id = p2.article_id)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..16889.70 rows=1 width=2488)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..16856.58 rows=4 width=2080)
                    Join Filter: (p.article_id = p3.article_id)
                    ->  Seq Scan on property p  (cost=0.00..8335.87 rows=115 width=1040)
                          Filter: ((int_value > 0) AND (int_value < 5) AND ((name)::text = 'hotel_stars'::text))
                    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..8336.41 rows=107 width=1040)
                          ->  Seq Scan on property p3  (cost=0.00..8335.87 rows=107 width=1040)
                                Filter: ((int_value > 0) AND (int_value < 7) AND ((name)::text = 'article_property_persons'::text))
              ->  Index Scan using article_pkey on article a  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=408)
                    Index Cond: (id = p.article_id)
                    Filter: is_active
        ->  Seq Scan on property p2  (cost=0.00..7185.05 rows=3115 width=1040)
              Filter: ((name)::text = 'article_property_journey_days'::text)
16 Datensätze

Laufzeit gesamt: 11.153 ms
```

Changing To

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* , p.*, p2.*, p3.*
    FROM article a 
    INNER JOIN pro p ON a.id = p.article_id AND p.name = 'hotel_stars' AND p.int_value > 0 AND p.int_value < 5
    INNER JOIN pro p2 ON a.id = p2.article_id AND p2.name = 'article_journey_days' 
    INNER JOIN pro p3 ON a.id = p3.article_id  AND p3.name = 'article_persons' AND p3.int_value > 0 AND p3.int_value < 7 
    WHERE a.is_active = true
```

Result:

```
319 Datensätze

Laufzeit gesamt: 9,315.863 ms

HashAggregate  (cost=24113.80..24113.81 rows=1 width=3528)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..24113.69 rows=1 width=3528)
        Join Filter: (a.id = p2.article_id)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..16889.70 rows=1 width=2488)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..16856.58 rows=4 width=2080)
                    Join Filter: (p.article_id = p3.article_id)
                    ->  Seq Scan on property p  (cost=0.00..8335.87 rows=115 width=1040)
                          Filter: ((int_value > 0) AND (int_value < 5) AND ((name)::text = 'hotel_stars'::text))
                    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..8336.41 rows=107 width=1040)
                          ->  Seq Scan on property p3  (cost=0.00..8335.87 rows=107 width=1040)
                                Filter: ((int_value > 0) AND (int_value < 7) AND ((name)::text = 'article_property_persons'::text))
              ->  Index Scan using article_pkey on article a  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=408)
                    Index Cond: (id = p.article_id)
                    Filter: is_active
        ->  Seq Scan on property p2  (cost=0.00..7185.05 rows=3115 width=1040)
              Filter: ((name)::text = 'article_property_journey_days'::text)
16 Datensätze

Laufzeit gesamt: 4.314 ms
```

Similar question :(

Comment: explain plan - indexes? amount of data?

Comment: added the explain plan. property table ~ 2000 articles ~ 460

Comment: `where` clauses that concern only the joined table should be moved in the left join `on` section

Comment: @ foibs i tried but similar results :/

Comment: LEFT JOIN property p ON a.id = p.article_id AND p.name = 'hotel_stars' AND p.int_value > 0 AND p.int_value < 5 (ignores the last part with int_value and show all results)

Comment: @Wykk : I forgot to say that it should also be inner join (just as you wrote in your comment, but with `INNER` instead of `LEFT`). Do you have index on `pro.article_id`?

Comment: @ foibs i edit it see reedit post but nothing changed on the speed :(

Comment: Do you need the * for all tables? Can u try indexing name column (with 460 records, may not make a difference)

Comment: @Wykk hey, sorry, one last thing. Can you swap `a.id = p.article_id` for all 3 joins so it will be `p.article_id = a.id` ?

Comment: @ foibs nothing happend

Comment: @ jayadevan i have not much columns in the tables so * is not the point, i wrote all nessecary culoums manuall but no difference.
The index on name improved speed from 9 sec to 980 ms but it should work faster or not?

Comment: @Wykk, if you delete the `DISTINCT` work, how many rows are returned?

Comment: I added an index for name and article_id. This made my day. Speed from 13sec down to 180ms. 
Thx you guys for helping this find out :)

Answer (score 1):

Added Index for column p.name and p.article.
Result speed improve from 13sec to 180ms.